# How to commit to Sourceforge using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, sourceforge

I have directory named "Proyectos" with Django code inside.

I need to commit the project to Source Forge so my teacher can "download" all the code to his computer.

I think I should use some of these address:

```
http://phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan (read-only) 
 ssh://lucasab@phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan (read/write)
```

I did this on Kubuntu:

```
lucas@lucas-Satellite-L305:~/Desarrollo/Python/Django/Proyectos$ hg clone http://phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/django-mercurial
```

but only the folder is created.

I'm a novice and didn't find how to do this. I followed some tutorials but I can't understand a lot of concepts.

I would appreciate some assistance with this, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Rob Sobers and Krtek for their answers. I finally could add all my files to SourceForge. I followed their instructions and everything went fine, although I had some minor complications.

This is the answer to my questions step by step:

Over the folder "Proyectos" I did:

- `hg clone ssh://lucasab@phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan` and entered the password for my SourceForge account. A folder "phone-apps-djan" was created.
- `hg add` after I `cd` into `phone-apps-djan` and copied all the files of my project into that folder.
- `hg commit`. There was an error at this point: `abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")`. So I created a file named `.hgrc` in my home dir and added these lines:

  ```
  [ui]
  username = my username at sourceforce <the mail address I supplied when registering>
  verbose = True
  ```

Then I re-entered `hg commit`.

- `hg push`. The follow error message was displayed: `abort: repository default-push not found!`. Then I just re-edited the .hgrc file created on the last step and added:

  ```
  [paths]
  default = ssh://lucasab@phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-dja
  ```

I really don't understand what happened here because the `.hg` directory in my repo already contains a `hgrc` file with that path :(. Anyway, I did `hg push` again.

And that was all.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different address to access your Mercurial repository on sourceforge :

1. `http://phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan (read-only)`, like said after the address, this one is read-only, it is for everyone to clone your project, so they can see the sources and compile / use it. There's no authentication. When you use this address, Mercurial use the HTTP protocol to pull the changes.
2. `ssh://lucasab@phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan (read/write)`, you can write to your repository through this address, but you have to authenticate yourself (you'll have to enter your password) and Mercurial use the SSH protocol to do that. You can also see your sourceforge username in the address.

First of all, you must do another clone of your project with the second address, otherwise you won't be able to commit. Just `cd` in a new directory and do :

```
hg clone ssh://lucasab@phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan
```

You should be prompted for your sourceforge account password.

Then, you can cd in the newly created directory, do all your changes, add files, etc. When you're done, you can do a `hg commit`and then a `hg push` to publish the modification to your repository. If you add new file to the directory don't forget to do a `hg add` or `hg addremove`.

You can find a really good and simple tutorial about mercurial on [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/), you should read it and try to understand the workflow before doing anything on sourceforge.

Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing `hg clone` downloaded the repository to your computer.  Now, to update your working directory (so you can work with the files), type `hg update`.

When you're done making changes, type `hg commit` to record them.  When you're ready upload your changes to SourceForge, type `hg push http://path/to/repo`.  Make sure you push up to the correct repository!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob. This is what I do: first, I manually copy all the files from an already existing project to a new folder named "Proyectos", then I cd into that folder. Once there, I do "hg commit" and then "hg push http://phone-apps-djan.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/phone-apps-djan/phone-apps-djan
" in order to upload all the files to SourceForge. But this message is displayed: no changes found. So I think I'm doing something wrong because it seems that the files are not being  uploaded... please help one more time.  Cheers!.

Comment: the `hg push` won't work, Lucas cloned the repository with the read-only address, SF will refuse any incoming change.

Comment: @Krtek it should work as long as he specifies the destination path when pushing and doesn't use the `default-push` path, which will be the read-only address.

Comment: yeah, but you should have done a little explanation about the two addresses then and it's always easier to have the read/write url as the default path. I don't think Lucas has many notion about Mercurial yet, I'm afraid your answer won't help him much. @Lucas did you add your file to the working directory ? you can see my answer for a link to a good tutorial.

Comment: @Lucas After you manually copy your files into the "Proyectos", cd into the folder and type `hg add` then type `hg commit` then `hg push`